# Cannot Install OrangeScrum on XAMPP in Windows?

Tags: php, xampp, cakephp-2.0

I have downloaded OrangeScrum to install on my local PC using XAMPP.

I have created a database and imported it to my database. Also created user in database and granted all privileges.

Moreover, I tried to `chmod` to `777` on Windows but it still alerted the message.

[image: Here is my screenshot].

Comment: I don't see any error message in the screenshot you attached. May be that is just a reminder notice. However if you receive any error in the later stage, make sure both the directories `tmp` and `webroot` exist. You can do this manually by creating the directories on your own thru the Windows.

Comment: could you explain me more please?

Comment: On clicking sign up do you receive any errors?

Comment: no but now i can solve it. i don't why when i type my IP address replace with localhost it work. but when i use only localhost when i sign up it still stay on this page.

Comment: I have the same problem. did you find any solution. I am using virtual host instead of localhost